# How to ignore directories using RecursiveIteratorIterator?

Tags: php, iterator

I have tried several methods to ignore certain directories using `RecursiveIteratorIterator` on a file system.

For the sake of an example say I want to ignore the following directory: `/cache`.

My `Iterator` looks like this:

```
//$dirname is root
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dirname);
$mega = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($mega as $fileinfo) {
 echo $fileinfo;
}
```

I have been able to ignore certain file extensions using `pathinfo` for example this works:

```
$filetypes = array("jpg", "png");
$filetype = pathinfo($fileinfo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

foreach ($mega as $fileinfo) {
    if (!in_array(strtolower($filetype), $filetypes)) {
    echo $fileinfo;
    }
}
```

When I try it using `PATHINFO_DIRNAME` (with the appropriate directory paths in the array) it does not work, there are no errors, it just does not ignore the directories.

I have also experimented with using `FilterIterator` to no avail, and now I'm thinking maybe I should use `RegexIterator`.

What would be the simplest and most efficient way to ignore directories using `RecursiveIteratorIterator` ?

---

Experiments that didn't work.
Using `PATHINFO_DIRNAME`

```
$dirignore = array("cache", "cache2");
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dirname);
$mega = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$dirtype = pathinfo($fileinfo, PATHINFO_DIRNAME); 

if (!in_array($dirtype), $dirignore)) {
echo $fileinfo;  //no worky still echo directories
}
```

Using `FilterIterator` (not sure how this works)

```
class DirFilter extends FilterIterator
{
    public function accept()
    {
        //return parent::current() != "..\cache\";

       $file = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
       if ($file != "..\cache")
       return $file->getFilename();

      //also tried with same error as below
      //return !preg_match('/\cache', $file->getFilename());
    }
}

$directory= new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dirname);
$directory = new DirFilter($directory); 
$mega = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
// loop
```

Tis results in `Error: An instance of RecursiveIterator or IteratorAggregate creating it is required`

Comment: What did your experiments with FilterIterator look like? It sounds like you were on the right track.

Comment: Updated with 2 examples that don't work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `DirFilter` wants to extend `RecursiveFilterIterator`, since it is being used with a recursive iterator.  Not doing that, is the cause of your error.

```
class DirFilter extends RecursiveFilterIterator
{
    // …
}
```

The next step is figuring out how to use `accept()` properly.  It is supposed to return a `true` or `false` value, which dictates whether the current item should be included (`true`) or excluded (`false`) from the iteration.  Returning a file name from `accept()` is not what you want to be doing.

```
class DirFilter extends RecursiveFilterIterator
{
    public function accept()
    {
        $excludes = array("cache", "cache2");
        return !($this->isDir() && in_array($this->getFilename(), $excludes));
    }
}
```

---

It might be nice to be able to pass in the array of excluded directories. This requires a little more code but is much more reusable.

```
class DirFilter extends RecursiveFilterIterator
{
    protected $exclude;
    public function __construct($iterator, array $exclude)
    {
        parent::__construct($iterator);
        $this->exclude = $exclude;
    }
    public function accept()
    {
        return !($this->isDir() && in_array($this->getFilename(), $this->exclude));
    }
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return new DirFilter($this->getInnerIterator()->getChildren(), $this->exclude);
    }
}
```

This code could then be used like:

```
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dirname);
$filtered = new DirFilter($directory, $dirignore); 
$mega = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($filtered, …);
```

Comment: Thanks this makes much more sense, but nothing I do (using both methods) actually seems to filter the directories out, it's the same case as in my `PATHINFO_DIRNAME` example ( no errors, directory still visible on output) , I wonder if this has something to do with being on windows. I have also hardcoded the path (`D:\Sites\Bar12/wp-content\cache`)in the exclude and tried several variations and nada.

Comment: That sounds more like a PEBKAC error.  The above will definitely filter those directories, **even** on Windows.

Comment: Thank you for posting this.  Filtering out directories within the iterator, instead of looping over it's results, reduced my script's processing time from over 30 seconds to just 3 seconds when searching my entire server!

Comment: to add to @FrankJance comment. thanks for posting this about extending RecursiveFilterIterator. This reduced my script that recursively iterates through a bunch of files and folders from a time of 19 minutes and 54 seconds to just 1 minute and 12 seconds.