# PHP Ignore an array of directories using RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Tags: php

I have this code in PHP which i am using to list all my directories and files:

```
$path=__DIR__;
// List of directories / files to be ignored.
//
$ignoreDir = array('/home/integra/public_html/admin/phpMailer');

//Quick patch to add full path to Ignore
$ignoreDir = array_map(function ($var) use($path) {
    return $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $var;
}, $ignoreDir);

$ite = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
foreach ( new RecursiveIteratorIterator($ite) as $filename => $object ) {

    if (in_array($filename, $ignoreDir))
        continue;

    echo $filename . '<br />';
}
```

i have a variable (`$ignoreDir`) which is an array of different folders to not display in my list but its still displaying them. In the above example i have used:

```
$ignoreDir = array('/home/integra/public_html/admin/phpMailer');
```

i have also tried:

```
$ignoreDir = array('phpMailer');
```

and

```
$ignoreDir = array('admin/phpMailer');
```

how can i get it to not display the directories, and files within

Comment: Your best bet would be to "echo" the directories returned by the iterator (just before your if) and work out what the inconsistency is by looking at the data you're processing.

Comment: i tried changing to: if (in_array($filename, $ignoreDir))
 {
  //ignore
 }
 else
 {
  echo $filename . '<br />';
 } but that didn't work

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369291/how-to-ignore-directories-using-recursiveiteratoriterator